# Call jQuery Function from code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, popupwindow

How would I call this jquery function from my code behind page. Im clueless what the syntax would be. Any helo would be greatly apreciated. It pops a window for users to register. I want to pop the page once the user views 5 pages on the site. Im goign to hold that count in a session variable.

Html page

```
<ul>

<li><a href="#dialog" name="modal">Simple Window Modal</a></li>

</ul>
div id="dialog" class="window">

<a href="#"class="close">Close it</a>
<br /><br />
Register Now its quick and Easy.<br />
Rules: 

        1) Items with "*" are required fields to be filled out.
        <br />
    </p>
    <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text="*Your Email: "></asp:Label><asp:TextBox
        ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
        ErrorMessage="You must enter your email address."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text="*Name: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="157px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName"
        ErrorMessage="You must enter a username."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text="*City: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Width="168px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCity"
        ErrorMessage="You must enter your location."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server" Text=" State: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtState" runat="server" Width="168px"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblAge" runat="server" Text="*Age: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" Width="165px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAge"
        ErrorMessage="Please enter your age to continue."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblSex" runat="server" Text="*Gender: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdMale" runat="server" GroupName="Gender" Text="Male" />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdFemale" runat="server" GroupName="Gender" Text="Female" />
    <asp:Label ID="RadialLBL" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblYahoo" runat="server" Text="Yahoo ID: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="YahooID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblMSN" runat="server" Text="MSN ID: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="MSNID" runat="server" Width="133px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblMyspaceLink" runat="server" Text="Your Myspace Link: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="MyspaceLink" runat="server" Width="255px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblFaceBookLink" runat="server" Text="Your FaceBook Link: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="FaceBooklink" runat="server" Width="244px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblUploadpic" runat="server" Text="*Upload your picture."></asp:Label>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="217px" /><br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblDesctiption" runat="server" Text="*User Bio: "></asp:Label><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" MaxLength="240" Width="390px" Height="73px"
        Rows="3" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="btnRegister_Click" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDescription"
        ErrorMessage="Enter a bio or description of yourself."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="EnterAll" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Displayme" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
```

Jquery function

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    //select all the a tag with name equal to modal
    $('a[name=modal]').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        //Get the A tag
        var id = $(this).attr('href');

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight });

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow", 0.8);

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top', winH / 2 - $(id).height() / 2);
        $(id).css('left', winW / 2 - $(id).width() / 2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000);

    });

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a sample snippet to register a script to the `Response`:

```
if(Session["_PageVisitCount"].ToString() == "5"){
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
        this.GetType(),
        "scriptsKey",
        "yourScriptMethodToCall();",
        true
    );
}
```

*After further reviewing your code, there isn't any client-side code that can be called explicitly. Are you missing any scripts?*

Comment: How could i change the jquery code to make it able to be called like a regualar function?

Comment: Correct, create a function in JavaScript that does what you want "pop a window". Then, when the conditions are right, register the script as I've exemplified.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be in code behind, you can wrap the code in an a code block in your ASPX file;

```
<% if( ( (int)Session["PageViews"] ) > 5 ) { %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // This code will only execute when PageViews > 5
    });
  </script>
<% } %>
```

Here we have just wrapped all code in a server-side check. If the check returns false, the code will not be rendered to the page.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call js scripts from the code behind. But, as others have shown, you can register s a script to call the jquery function when the response is sent back to the client.